# At the current stage, why most of the modern C++ compilers only support limited C++0x features, while Clang/GCC supports all of them?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, compiler-construction, clang

I am new to C++11, and found it is a difficult and tedious work to find alternative ways to make my code compatible with both Clang and Visual C++.

What's the reason behind this fact? Is that technique difficulties? Compatibility with old non-standard language extensions? Different priorities? Or any other possibilities?

The reference page: https://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport

Comment: That is unfortunate, but what is your question?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, “why…” questions are never good StackOverflow questions. http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous question. I wanted to ask what's the reason behind this fact. Is that technique difficulties? Compatibility with old non-standard language extensions? Different priorities? Or any other possibilities?

Comment: @PascalCuoq: That's a horrible rule of thumb...

Comment: @Mehrdad Complain to Meta about the “Ask questions, get answers, no distractions” slogan. I don't make the rules, but the rules are clearly that this is not the site for philosophical introspection.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Huh? You misunderstood what I said. I didn't say I think this is a good question for the site, I just said that your rule of thumb is horrible. There are *tons* of good "why" questions out there, that's not the reason why this question is bad.

Comment: @Mehrdad You're telling me. I just had to move 4 comments I wrote in a “why” question that I thought was going to be closed imminently to an answer , as it wasn't closed after all and I wanted to edit them.

Comment: @WeiXiang: "*I wanted to ask what's the reason behind this fact.*" What does it matter? How will it in any way change how you approach C++ programming? What *problem* will it solve?

Answer (score 4):

> Why most of the modern C++ compilers only support limited C++0x features, while Clang supports all of them?

clang was designed much later than most of the other major compilers, and was built in a way that makes it easier to support some of the modern features.  Many other compilers, such as MSVC and GCC, support many other targets than clang, and have a large legacy code base.  Changes to these compilers tends to come more slowly over time.

> and found it is a difficult and tedious work to find alternative ways to make my code compatible with both Clang and Visual C++.

In general, I've found that if you stick to the subset (in this case, write for Visual C++), then clang will typically support the code with no changes, provided you avoid the Microsoft language extensions.  Moving the other direction is often more challenging.

Comment: "Many other compilers (...) support many other targets". If targets means languages than clang depends on LLVM so the whole compiler infrastructure is more or less open to new languages. If you mean target platforms than the LLVM supports many platforms as well.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka LLVM supports many platforms, but at this point in time, GCC supports more.  This is even listed directly on clang's site: http://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html  See the GCC pros

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I don't think the same is true for Visual C++.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka In practice, it may not matter, but it *does* impact why GCC is behind clang for some features

Comment: @Mehrdad VC++ supports quite a few other targets, such as the C++/CLI and C++/Cx extension sets, etc.  It also has a huge number of Windows specific extensions...

Comment: @ReedCopsey: Oh I see what you mean. I misunderstood what you meant by targets, sorry.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka Restricting myself to VC++ feature sets is convenient. But sometimes I felt it is not the best way for achieving the cleanest code. VC++ (even with the Nov 2012 CTP), misses some of the features I really like to use (inherited constructors, e.g.) As I believe VC++ would eventually support that feature, I used the inherited constructors as the default path, while using #ifdef to create constructors for VC++.

Comment: @WeiXiang Yes, until the point in time VC++ will support this, you either need to make 2 versions (which has it's own maintenance issues) or restrict to the older subset.  I'm sure it'll catch up - and you can vote for specific features on the user voice site, but it's just an unfortunate fact of life that it's a bit behind for now.

Answer (score 2):

Because the changes on Visual seems to take time, like in GCC. GCC almost support everything.

But also it is a question of priority. In fact GCC was full C++11 complete before CLang oficially (even if this was just because CLang was waiting for the official release date with everything ready).

Visual takes more time because they also spend energy in making the IDE better. And they have less developers.

Comment: Yes, I missed the GCC. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.